# how to group data by more than two factors in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like below.
In real data set, there are 8619 rows.

```
Athlete      Competing Country  Year    Total Medals
Michael Phelps    United States 2012    6
Alicia Coutts     Australia     2012    5
Missy Franklin    United States 2012    5
Brian Leetch      United States 2002    1
Mario Lemieux     Canada        2002    1
Ylva Lindberg     Sweden        2002    1
Eric Lindros      Canada        2002    1
Ulrica Lindström  Sweden        2002    1
Shelley Looney    United States 2002    1
```

and I want to rearrange this data by country, year and the sum of the medals.

I want result like

```
Country        Year  SumOfMedals
United States  2012  11
United States  2002   2
...

by(newmd$Total.Medals, newmd$Year, FUN=sum)
by(md$Total.Medals, md$Competing.Country, FUN=sum)
```

I tired to use by argument, but still stuck.
Can any of you help me out?

Comment: `aggregate` not working for you?

Comment: aggregate(Total.Medals ~ Competing.Country, md, function(x) sum(x))

Comment: I tried this, but don't know how to sort the data by country and year at the same time.

Comment: You were almost there.  Try `aggregate(Total.Medals ~ Competing.Country + Year, md, sum)`

Comment: oh, that works. thank you!

Comment: J. Choi - Welcome to stack overflow! For future reference, you might like to look at [this Q&A about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this one about making reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using `aggregate` to get the sum of the number of medals:

```
md2 <- aggregate(cbind(SumOfMedals = Total.Medals) ~ Competing.Country + Year),
          data = md,
          FUN = sum)
```

The next step is to sort `md2` by `Competing.Country` and `SumOfMedals`, which is done using the `order` function:

```
md2 <- md2[order(Competing.Country, -SumOfMedals),]
```

All done.

Comment: @J.Choi if this works, please consider marking this as the answer by clicking on the green arrow to the left of my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Competing_Country', 'Year', get the `sum` of 'Total_Medals`and then`order` by the variables of interest.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(SumOfMedals = sum(Total_Medals)), 
   by = .(Competing_Country, Year)
        ][order(-Competing_Country, -Year, -SumOfMedals)]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we use the same methodology.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Competing_Country, Year) %>%
    summary(SumOfMedals = sum(Total_Medals) %>%
    arrange(desc(Competing_Country), desc(Year), desc(SumOfMedals))
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Athlete = c("Michael Phelps", "Alicia Coutts", 
"Missy Franklin", "Brian Leetch", "Mario Lemieux", "Ylva Lindberg", 
"Eric Lindros", "Ulrica Lindström", "Shelley Looney"), Competing_Country = c("United States", 
"Australia", "United States", "United States", "Canada", "Sweden", 
"Canada", "Sweden", "United States"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), Total_Medals = c(6L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Athlete", "Competing_Country", 
"Year", "Total_Medals"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```